# When should a toast arise in web app?

Tags: usability, notification, toast

When should a toast arise in web app (need psychological suggestion)?
Why `Add to favorite` action has no toast, while `Archive` or `Delete` actions have ones?

Toasts or snackbars are used for low-priority notifications, like pictured.

[image]

Comment: What kind of web app is this? Are favourites, archive and delete functions of this web app? What is favourited, archived or deleted?

Comment: The second part of your question is not really answerable by anyone here because it is specific to that app you're using. However, the first part of the question is valid. No need to close, just edit.

Comment: The difference between a favorite and an archive/delete is with a favorite, the item is likely still easily accessible in the UI. A toast (or something) is needed for archive/delete operations to allow the user an opportunity to undo a mistaken click.

Comment: @colmcq A toast is an alert or message that "pops up" like bread from a toaster, usually from the bottom right of the window or desktop.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn your comment makes more sense than current answers, do something about it.

Answer (score 3):

Answering your first question:

> When should a toast arise in web app?

A toast should arise directly after:

1. a user action has been completed
2. the system is now under a new state (e.g. error, warning or success)

The reason for a toast arising directly after actions or system changes is to provide immediate system feedback, which aims to reassure the user that their action is completed or not or if any state changes have occurred, and therefore it must be done in a timely manner.

In regards to your second question:

> Why Add to favorite action has no toast, while Archive or Delete actions have ones?

You'll have to ask the designers of the app in question. It's up to them so we cannot help you here other than a guess. My guess is that Archive and Delete removes the item from the list which is a "risky" action, if the user mistakenly taps this button at least they'll know what has happened to that list item. Whereas, Add to favourites, I guess, just add it to another list whilst not moving it from the current one.

Comment: really nice clarification #robbyreindeer, thank you for your time to answer my doubts.

Comment: What are the differences between system action and user action, if there are? E.g., user creates email in Gmail, but no toast is needed. Or is it non system action? For me this classification is unclear, as in interaction there are always two sides: a User and a System.

Comment: @AlexeyKolchenko - System action e.g. lost internet connection. - User action e.g. delete item.

Comment: But for the Delete action, which is User action, the toast is shown! It isn't aligned to your answer. Also, internet lost isn't action, rather state, which does aligned to your answer ).

Comment: @AlexeyKolchenko I've changed the wording of system action to user action as this was a mistake on my part. As for the 'delete' part I'm not sure I understand your quarrel. I've not suggested that user actions shouldn't have toasts at any point, in fact the opposite is true.

Comment: @MadhanRaj you're welcome, and as a new user, you should know that you can mark answers as 'accepted' if it solves your problem. Alternatively you can wait for a better answer...

Answer (score 1):

From my UX viewpoint, notifications as toasts are good once I'm as a end-user is informed with something that is not so important or I'm surely aware of it as I triggered it explicitly, AND there is no damage if the toast is missed by me at all (let say, I'm eventually turned to my coffee machine for the next drink, or massaging  my closed eyes etc.)

In case you need to be sure the notification is read, you could show closable banner (so it stays visible until X-clicked, however it's not covering valuable information on the page (so end-user can keep his working with or without X-clicking the banner)

In case you have to stop any further end-user action before reacting on the notification, use local popups.